# Change value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textarea2').click(function() {
        $("textarea").html('<input type="text" value="hello">');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="textarea2">Click here</button>   

<input type="text" class="form-name"  value="Name">
<input type="text" class="form-email" value="E-mail">
<input type="text" class="form-phone" id="textarea">
```

I would change the last row with a different value..

I click on button, but my code doesn't work. Maybe it's a problem with jquery

Comment: your selector is not corrrect for ##$("selecor")## and you need to use val instead of html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `#` in your selector: `$('#textarea')`. And, you don't need to replace the entire DOM for the element. Just use `val()`

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Answer (score 1):

Just as you used a `#` to indicate that `textarea2` was an id, you need to do the same thing for `textarea`.

Comment: Thanks in advance! I need to sleep too tired

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textarea2').click(function() {
       $('#textarea').val('hello');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="textarea2">Click here</button>   

<input type="text" class="form-name"  value="Name">
<input type="text" class="form-email" value="E-mail">
<input type="text" class="form-phone" id="textarea">
```